# Download dependencies given only the build.gradle file

Tags: java, docker, gradle, docker-compose

Is it possible to download gradle dependencies using only `build.gradle` file?

What I am trying to accomplish is the following:

I have a set of unit tests and I want to execute them (as part of CI process) inside a docker container. Initially, I used the [openjdk:8-jdk](https://store.docker.com/images/openjdk) image from docker hub as base image for my tests. So, docker compose file contains the following:

```
version: '3.2'

services:

  unit:
    image: openjdk:8-jdk
    volumes:
      - ..:/usr/test
    working_dir: /usr/test
    command: sh -c "exec ./gradlew junitPlatformTest -Punit -p moduleA/"
```

Whole project is mounted on `/usr/test` directory inside the container. When the container starts, it executes the `junitPlatformTest` task against `moduleA`. The problem with `openjdk:8-jdk` image is that gradle and its dependencies are downloaded every time I run the `unit` service.

To solve this, I decided to create a new image which would have gradle and my project dependencies already downloaded. The `Dockerfile` is the following:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk
COPY . /usr/test
WORKDIR /usr/test
RUN apt-get -y install wget unzip
RUN wget https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-bin.zip
RUN mkdir /opt/gradle
RUN unzip -d /opt/gradle gradle-4.1-bin.zip
RUN /opt/gradle/gradle-4.1/bin/gradle dependencies
```

The `build.gradle` file is located in same folder as Dockerfile so the command `COPY . /usr/test` copies it in the working directory.

However, executing the `gradle dependencies` command does not download the libraries. After built the image, ran a container and entered into it (with docker exec), it seems that `~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/` directory contains only pom files, not jars.

I'm not use if `gradle dependencies` is the correct command. Any suggestions?

**EDIT - Gradle file**

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

ext.versions = new Properties()
file("./versions.properties").withInputStream {
    stream -> ext.versions.load(stream)
}

dependencies {
    testCompile("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:$versions.junitJupiterVersion")
    testCompile("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:$versions.junitJupiterVersion")
    testCompile("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:$versions.junitJupiterVersion")
    testCompile("org.mockito:mockito-core:'$versions.mockitoCore")
    testCompile("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:1.0.0-RC3")

    compile("com.google.inject:guice:$versions.guice")
    ....
}
```

Comment: can you provide ur gradle file?

Comment: Please share gradle file in your question

Comment: @yamenk, Tarun Lalwani added gradle file

Comment: @Schaliasos, see my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add below to your gradle file

```
 task download (type: Exec) {
     configurations.testCompile.files
     commandLine 'echo', 'Downloaded all dependencies'

  }
```

Also change

```
RUN /opt/gradle/gradle-4.1/bin/gradle dependencies
```

to

```
RUN /opt/gradle/gradle-4.1/bin/gradle
```

This will cache all dependencies to `~/.gradle` when you run the gradle command. It will download the jars also and not just poms. And if you want to cache further you can even use a named volume for gradle folder

```
version: '3.2'

services:

  unit:
    image: openjdk:8-jdk
    volumes:
      - ..:/usr/test
      - gradlecache:/root/.gradle/
    working_dir: /usr/test
    command: sh -c "exec ./gradlew junitPlatformTest -Punit -p moduleA/"
volumes:
  gradlecache: {}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your idea is right but the approach is wrong. First of all, there is no need to download and install Gradle manually, that's exactly what the [Gradle Wrapper](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html) does for you. Second of all, there is no need to hack Gradle to force download dependencies - it doesn't make any sense. Just check out/clone your test project from inside the container and run your tests with `./gradlew clean test`. There is no need for a local `/usr/test` directory, which is flies in the face of CI, because it uses a relative location, and hence only works when you've laid out files in an exact manner.

**Edit**:
If you don't want to download Gradle or the dependencies for every build, you can start the container by volume mapping the`$HOME/.m2` directory to the host, so that dependencies downloaded once stay in the Maven local cache. To avoid downloading Gradle, you can build your own Docker image with Gradle in it.

Comment: If I understand him right, he does not want to download everything (wrapper and dependencies) for each new container installation.

Comment: You don't want to copy in `$HOME/.m2`, because that will mask issues with bad repositories or locally-cached jars. Other users might not be able to repeat your build that way. It'll also be relatively slow (it needs to be re-checksummed each build, and will be updated by other projects using a maven cache).

Comment: @jkinkead Nobody said anything about copying `$HOME/.m2`, read my response again

Comment: Sorry, you said to *map* it in - but that has the same issues with repeatability. It doesn't have the slow-start issues that copying does.

Comment: Downloading deps separately in a Dockerfile is useful so that it reuses layer caching efficiently. The poster doesn't articulate this, but I imagine that's what they're trying to do. Mounting host dir is not great if you want reproducible builds.